# Kotter Dual Operation Model

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, mindmaps

I'm trying to build Kotter's Dual Operation Model, consisting of a hierarchy on the left and a network on the right side.

[image: Kotter's Dual Operation Model]

Actually I think it can be achieved using "forest" and "mindmap". Im not sure about:

- Is this the right way to do it
- How to get the hierarchy on the left, the network on the right

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,times,forest,array,geometry}
    \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap,backgrounds,shadows}
    \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=40},extra concept/.append style={color=blue!50,text=black}]

% Area1 Initiative
\begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=orange, text=white]
  \node [concept] {Initiative}[clockwise from=-5] 
      child {node [concept] (log) {Subinitiaves}}
      child {node [concept] (alg) {Subinitiaves}}
      child {node [concept] (cod) {Subinitiaves}}
      child {node [concept] (img) {Subinitiaves}}
      child {node [concept] (opt) {Subinitiaves}}
      child {node [concept] (res) {Subinitiaves}}
      child {node [concept] (res) {Subinitiaves}};
\end{scope}

  % Area 2 Initiative
\begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=red,text=white]
  \node [concept] at (-3,-10) {Initiative}
      child [grow=-10, level distance=160]{node [concept] (qin) {Subinitiaves}}
      child [grow=150] {node [concept] (csm) {Subinitiaves}}
      child [grow=110] {node [concept] (mat) {Subinitiaves}};
\end{scope}

% Area 3 Initiative
\begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=green!50!black,text=white]
  \node [concept] at (8,-10) {Initiative} 
      child [grow=165, level distance=120] {node [concept] (med) {Subinitiaves}}
      child [grow=60] {node [concept] (gen) {Subinitiaves}}
      child [grow=120] {node [concept] (gen) {Subinitiaves}};
  \end{scope}

% Area 3 Initiative (one subfield)
\begin{scope}[mindmap, concept color=violet, text=white]
  \node [concept] at (11,-1) {Initiative}
      child [grow=70, level distance=120] {node [concept] (dec) {Subinitiative}}
      child [grow=70, level distance=10] {node [concept] (dec) {Subinitiative}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
      if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
        align={@{}C{25mm}@{}},
      },
      draw,
      font=\sffamily\bfseries,
      edge path={
        \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      },
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      l sep=10mm,
      tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
      edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
      ultra thick,
      inner color=gray!5,
      outer color=gray!20,
      rounded corners=2pt,
      drop shadow,
    }
    [multiple line\\text
      [text]
      [very long single line text]
      [text
        [text]
        [text]
        [text]
      ]
      [text]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you put the `forest` before the mindmap in the source and don't leave a blank line between them, you'll get the tree on the left and the map on the right. However, you will still need to make them fit on the page. Using `sidewaysfigure` or similar (from the `rotating` package) might help.